# unauthorize access with authorization header signalr

Tags: c#, authorization, signalr

I'm using signalR and I'm trying to get the `[Authorize]` attribute to work. With below setup I get 401 Unauthorized..

Right before I start the Hub I set the Authorization like this:

```
$.signalR.ajaxDefaults.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + settingsService.getItem('authData').token }
```

I can see that the header is sent in the request like below:

> Authorization: Bearer F0wGNa7cAwUjOFI27TDR_w7N4Ncmz66PGpsU1AH2AWt0Gdt39e2o4DGwPsBXTAlIwHrAF-YHE9I1KGLxfabE0QxpcY5mLn1gxGWStOSX_W5NaUQlRlpRu5k-s6YLH-vVjlakqap_YXbzPelZJOjwcz7Ea5VHcCUFQ5xDYYK0VJXDIqMwQXZPIyVtNVu1RyLLVj7iOZaMd-41gHKWNqFWJBmK5WkWw06dI4AWiifWJT_8v1WrFPCAzYfiT0U

My Hub:

```
[Authorize]
[HubName("myHub")]
public class DataHub : Hub {
    private static bool _isInitated;

    public DataHub() {
         //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

The token is created like this:

```
var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Username", "myname"));

        var properties = new AuthenticationProperties() {
            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Add(Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan)
        };

        var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, properties);
        var accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

        var response = new JObject(new JProperty("access_token", accessToken), new JProperty("expires_in", Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan.TotalMinutes));

        return Ok(new { token = response });
```

Am I missing something special here? Don't really get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is an issue for someone else I got the answer here. In my startup.cs I had to move `app.MapSignalR();` last in the Configuration method. Like below:

```
public class Startup {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
        CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DefaultMessageBufferSize = 100;
        ConfigureOAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }

    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app) {
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(7)
        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    }
}
```

Before I had `ConfigureOAuth(app);` last.. and then it didn't work

Comment: Thank you! I searched for hours trying to solve this problem. This was exactly what I needed.